# How to get specific data from nested JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to get the nested station names using jQuery and display the names in a 'div'. I'm able to display the contents of 'jObject' however, I'm unable to get to the specific station name.

This is what i have tried so far.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://transportapi.com/v3/uk/tube/stations/near.json?app_id=appid&app_key=key&lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lng + "&page=1&rpp=5",
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        //console.log(data);
        var jObject = data.stations;
        // $('#stationName').append(JSON.stringify(jObject));  
        $.each(jObject.name, function(index, element) {
            $('#stationName').append(JSON.stringify(jObject.name));
        });
    }
});
```

JSON structure

```
{
    "minlon": -0.23437,
    "minlat": 51.434842,
    "maxlon": -0.03437,
    "maxlat": 51.634842,
    "searchlon": -0.13437,
    "searchlat": 51.534842,
    "page": 1,
    "rpp": 1,
    "total": 147,
    "request_time": "2018-03-09T17:15:22+00:00",
    "stations": [
        {
            "station_code": "MCR",
            "atcocode": "9400ZZLUMTC",
            "name": "Mornington Crescent",
            "mode": "tube",
            "longitude": -0.13878,
            "latitude": 51.53468,
            "lines": [
                "northern"
            ],
            "distance": 492
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `jObject[0].name`  stations is an array. `{}` object. `[]` array

Comment: API's Keys were exposed on the code.  
Make sure to regenerate the API Key on the API Website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong in your code:
`$.each()` will iterate on an array, since you already define `data.stations` as `jObject`, you need to iterate `in` that array.

`$.each` function takes to parameters `index` and `element`, the first one is the position of the element in the array, and the second has the element itself.
So the code will be:

```
var jObject = data.stations;

$.each(jObject, function(index, element) {
  $('#stationName').append(element.name);  
});
```

Check the [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pdc3vv7r/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Most helpful and much appreciated! Cheers

Answer (score 3):

You should use `$each` on `jObject` and not on `jObject.name`. And you need to specify index while getting name as  `stations` is an array of objects or just use `element.name`

```js
var data={
    "minlon": -0.23437,
    "minlat": 51.434842,
    "maxlon": -0.03437,
    "maxlat": 51.634842,
    "searchlon": -0.13437,
    "searchlat": 51.534842,
    "page": 1,
    "rpp": 1,
    "total": 147,
    "request_time": "2018-03-09T17:15:22+00:00",
    "stations": [
        {
            "station_code": "MCR",
            "atcocode": "9400ZZLUMTC",
            "name": "Mornington Crescent",
            "mode": "tube",
            "longitude": -0.13878,
            "latitude": 51.53468,
            "lines": [
                "northern"
            ],
            "distance": 492
        }
    ]
};
var jObject = data.stations;
   

$.each(jObject, function(index, element) {
  console.log(jObject[index].name);
  console.log(element.name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```